# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I found many similar questions but I was not able to resolve this issue, Hence posting a new one.

I have developed dotnet core web application with login/register functionalities. In the edit profile section, there is a functionality where the user can update his profile picture. This is perfectly working fine in the local. When I deploy this to the server I am getting the below-mentioned error.

[image]

code for your reference

```
        private Dictionary<string, string> UploadProfilePic(EditUserProfilePicViewModel model)
    {
        string uniqueFileName = null;
        Dictionary<string, string> imageNamesMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        string contentRoot = config.GetValue<string>(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey);
        string tempFolder = contentRoot + "\\wwwroot\\images\\temp";
        string uploadFolder = contentRoot + "\\wwwroot\\images\\profilepics";

        if (model.ProfileImage != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] fileNameArray = model.ProfileImage.FileName.ToString().Split('.');
                string fileExtension = fileNameArray[fileNameArray.Length - 1];
                uniqueFileName = model.ProfileId.ToString() + '-' + model.ProfileUrl + "." + fileExtension;

                //store image in the temp folder
                string filePath = Path.Combine(tempFolder, uniqueFileName);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    model.ProfileImage.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

                using (Image sourceImage = Image.FromFile(filePath))
                {
                    if (sourceImage != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //resize to 300px and store in profilepics folder
                            using (Image destinationImage = ResizeImage(sourceImage, 300, 300))
                            {
                                uniqueFileName = model.ProfileId.ToString() + '-' + model.ProfileUrl + "-300." + fileExtension;
                                imageNamesMap.Add("LargeImage", uniqueFileName);
                                string fileSavePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, uniqueFileName);
                                destinationImage.Save(fileSavePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            }

                            //resize to 75px and store in profilepics folder
                            using (Image destinationImage = ResizeImage(sourceImage, 75, 75))
                            {
                                uniqueFileName = model.ProfileId.ToString() + '-' + model.ProfileUrl + "-75." + fileExtension;
                                imageNamesMap.Add("SmallImage", uniqueFileName);
                                string fileSavePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, uniqueFileName);
                                destinationImage.Save(fileSavePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                DeleteFilesFromDir(tempFolder);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return imageNamesMap;
    }
```

could you please help me with this?

Comment: Are you using IIS to host your application, and if so, what user account and environment variables are configured for it.  Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=netcore-3.1&tabs=windows to see how the temporary file path is resolved.  My guess is the account the application is run under doesn't have a correct `TMP`, `TEMP`, `USERPROFILE` environment variable defined.

Comment: Matthew is right, also you should recosider writing to temp as it's not maintained by you and someone can decide to remove files actively used, better use a file in your app_data folder and maintain the files your self, perhaps empty on try-finally or and at start-up op your website

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the user account your application is using for running on the server doesn't have access to the mentioned path (you can login on a server with a privileged account and launch your app to confirm that).
Any application is a system process that is running from specific user account, this may be a real local server account (SERVERNAME\user), Active Directory account (DIRECTORYNAME\user) or some virtual account. In case you're using IIS for hosting your app on a server, then most probably it will use virtual IIS account to launch app processes (IIS APPPOOL<apppoolname>). To resolve the issue you need to get the app pool name your app is using (ex. myapppool), go to the problematic folder's properties security tab and add proper access rights (Write in your case) for user 'IIS APPPOOL\myapppool'. After that once you restart the app it will be able to create files there.